# D3 Graph Drawing with labels, first few labels won't appear

Tags: javascript, d3.js

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3b8Ax/4/

I've created random data, and graphed it using d3 while trying to learn it.  When putting labels on the bars however, the first 6 never get a label, and I'm going crazy trying to find out why.  Does anyone have any input?  I'm still learning, so the code is probably very un-optimized and messy.  Thanks!

Text drawing function:

```
            svg.selectAll("text").data(dataset).enter().append("text")
                .text(function (d) {  return d; })
                .attr("x", function (d, i) { console.log(dataset);return i * ((w - SidebarPadding) / dataset.length) + SidebarPadding + (w / dataset.length - padding) / 2; })
                .attr("y", function (d) {
                    if (scale(d) > (h - 10)) { return h - 2; }
                    return scale(d) + 10;
                })
                .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                .attr("font-size", "11px")
                .attr("fill", "orange")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("font-size", "50%");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is related to how selections work. You're doing a `svg.selectAll("text")`, which selects all the text elements in the SVG. Then you match data to the selected elements using `.data()`. The key thing is that by default, D3 matches data and DOM elements by their index (i.e. the first DOM element is matched with the first data item and so on) and that there are text elements in your SVG already (the labels of the axis). So your selection isn't empty and part of the data is matched to those elements (the axis labels).

Therefore, the `.enter()` selection doesn't contain DOM elements for all the data elements, but only for those that are not matched. Hence you are missing exactly axis label number of elements.

One of the ways of fixing this is to assign a class to your labels and change the selector accordingly (e.g. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3b8Ax/5/) in the updated jsfiddle). Alternatively, you could simply add your labels before adding the axis.